# How to print out subfolder ksh?

Tags: ksh, subdirectory, ls

In the main folder, it contains a,b and c sub folder. I want to get every sub folder to be printed one by one..

```
 for d in ${ls -R main}
 do
     printf "$d"
 done
```

I would like it to print 
a
b
c
so that I can use these subfolder later to check permission....

Answer (score 0):

If You don't have to use only `ksh` You can do this with `find` like:

```
find /where/to/search/directories -type d -print
```

(`-type d` ensures that only directories will get find)

Or if You don't have `find` You can do it like:

```
ls -Rdl /path/to/search/directories/* | awk '/^d/ {print $9}'
```

`awk` parses `ls -l` output to filter out only directories and print the last field in the table.